# CSimpleArray crashed at RemoveAll

Tags: visual-c++, atl, heap-memory

I have an EXE that calls into a method in DLL.

The method in DLL is defined as, where CSimpleArray is ATL class:

```
class DriverUtility
{
    ....
    virtual bool GetFlagsOfRun(int runID, CSimpleArray<FlagData> &flags) = 0;
};

struct FlagData
{
    CString Name;
    CString Value;
    CString TypeName;
};
```

I call the method in EXE as

```
CSimpleArray<FlagData> m_mdFlags;
m_pDriverUtility->GetFlagsOfRun(m_lRunID, m_mdFlags);
```

When I call m_mdFlags.RemoveAll, it crashes at `free(m_aT);` with heap error at:

```
void RemoveAll()
   {
          if(m_aT != NULL)
          {
                 for(int i = 0; i < m_nSize; i++)
                       m_aT[i].~T();
                 free(m_aT);
                 m_aT = NULL;
          }
          m_nSize = 0;
          m_nAllocSize = 0;
}
```

I understand that when allocating memory on the heap it should be deallocated locally. I am creating the object in the caller (EXE) and also calling RemoveAll() from the caller, so not sure what the problem is here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method itself does not copy array and is unlikely to be the cause (though does not look safe to me in terms that it is not protect you from making other accidental errors).

I would say that you might be copying strings from the structures passed in array elements and eventually you have a mess with string allocators of DLL and EXE modules which result in an access violation. Make sure your caller does not copy that strings, if you need to make a copy, do this:

```
GetFlagsOfRun(..., flags) {
  FlagData& a = ...
  CString b = (LPCTSTR) a.Name; // Not a.Name directly!
  ...
}
```